# Hadoop on Window: localhost refuse to connect

Tags: hadoop

I am using Hadoop 2.7.0 and I downloaded It on Window 10

When I run:

```
start-all.cmd
```

And run:

```
jps
```

```
13520 Jps
6368 NodeManager
880 DataNode
8516 ResourceManager
8940 NameNode
```

Then go to Google Chrome and access:

```
localhost:9870
```

And It said: "**This site can’t be reached localhost** refused to connect."

[image]

I have tried to turn off my **FireWall,** but still not working.

Here are my Hadoop folders: F:\BigData\hadoop\etc\hadoop

- core-site.xml

  ```
  <configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
  </configuration>
  ```
- hdfs-site.xml

  ```
  <configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:\F:\BigData\hadoop\data\namenode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:\F:\BigData\hadoop\data\datanode</value>
    </property>
  </configuration>
  ```
- Thank you.

Comment: Port 50070 was used on older versions of Hadoop, I think. Why not upgrade to Hadoop 3?